# PHP Calendar/jQuery Datepicker Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I'm working with PHP Calendar and started playing around with the default themes. The default themes are hosted on a Google server, so I copy/pasted the files onto our server so I could change the themes. However, once hosted on our servers, the arrows for the month/week selection disappear (see pictures). Interestingly, it is only the graphic that disappears, as clicking on the blank spot where they should be correctly displays the dropdown.

I emailed the guy who created PHP Calendar, but the only help he could offer was that he used datepicker from jQuery, which I'm not too familiar with. Any help?

Thanks,
Philip

Correct Month/Week Selection: https://puu.sh/l1Jon/592160dc38.png

Incorrect Month/Week Selection: https://puu.sh/l1JkZ/8cd6ccd573.png

Comment: An example of the glitchy calendar is at the bottom of [this page](http://groupfitness.improvingfit.com)

Comment: open a chrome developer tools, tab Network, or whatever you use and check if there are any resources missing, maybe you get 404 on some for wrong address or youre just not authorised

Comment: At current time after inspecting with chrome developer tool, it shows **SIX** 404 Errors. Check those and solve the missing file

Comment: you can directly use jQuery datepicker from their library  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Gunasegar Thank you! That fixed my problem